# Issue reversing an array of object with a specific key in javascript (React)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, reverse

I fetch an external API and i have trouble reversing a specific key onClick on a table.

Here is my code:

```
[
  {
    id: 2353,
    name: "Some Product",
    current_price: 5413,
  },
  {
    id: 435,
    name: "Other Product",
    current_price: 159.766,
  },
]
```

```
  reversePrice = () => {
    const reversePrice = this.state.data.map(obj => obj.current_price);
    this.setState({
      data: reversePrice
    })
  }
```

```
 <Th onClick = {() => this.reversePrice()}>Price</Th>
```

Comment: What's the outcome that you get? What's the expected outcome?

Comment: Where are you actually reversing anything? `reversePrice` is just an array of price values ...

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'current_price' of undefined

Comment: Sorry i did:

  ```reversePrice.sort()```

Comment: I'm trying to onClick be able to toggle between highest price and lower price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sort your product instead of map.

```
products = products.sort((a,b)=> a.current_price - b.current_price);
```

```js
let products = [
{
id: 2353,
name: "Some Product",
current_price: 5413,
},
{
id: 435,
name: "Other Product",
current_price: 159.766,
},
];

products = products.sort((a,b)=> a.current_price - b.current_price);

console.log(products)
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it's not toggling, so if i want to go from lower price <=> highest price it's not working

Comment: you can input a parameter for it?

Comment: I'm gonna do with the sort and reverse the function with two buttons! thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'll need another state indicating current order(desc/asec) and use this info in your jsx.

```
reversePrice = () => {
    this.setState({
      desc: !this.state.desc
    })
}
```

And in the render function

```
const {data, desc} = this.state
const sortBy = (a, b) => (a.current_price - b.current_price) * (desc ? 1 : -1)
return <div> { data.sort(sortBy).map(item => <article> {JSON.stringify(item)} </article>) ) } </div>
```